# ActiveJob job is enqueued but then disappears from logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

We have thousands of jobs being processed by Resque but twice now a specific job is enqueued but never performed.

In the activejob log I can see it is enqueued:

> [ActiveJob] Enqueued SendMarketJob (Job ID: c37f2098-9f7b-4b73-a7f0-b6b44e057535) to Resque(console_high) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f19f34a1848 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://console/Market/57141>>

But after that it disappears.

Normally I would see something like the following:

> [ActiveJob] [SendMarketJob] Performing SendMarketJob (Job ID: c37f2098-9f7b-4b73-a7f0-b6b44e057535) from Resque(console_high) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x000000000767cd50 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://console/Market/57141>
>
> [ActiveJob] [SendMarketJob] Performed SendMarketJob (Job ID: c37f2098-9f7b-4b73-a7f0-b6b44e057535) from Resque(console_high) in 4878.01ms

Any thoughts on how this could happen?

And is there any logging I can add to see why it happens, if it happens again?

- Rails version: 5.8.2.1
- Resque version: 2.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37830#issue-530096028) issue on GitHub this version of ActiveJob can say that a job is enqueued when it actually isn't. I think this is the most likely scenario.

From the linked issue:

> Fix ActiveJob logging when callback chain is halted:
>
> Problem:
>
> ActiveJob will always log "Enqueued MyJob (Job ID) ..." even
> if the job doesn't get enqueued through the adapter. Same problem
> happens when performing a Job, "Performed MyJob (Job ID) ..." will be
> logged even when job wasn't performed at all. This situation can
> happen either if the callback chain is terminated (before_enqueue
> throwing an abort) or if an exception is raised.
>
> Solution:
>
> Check if the callback chain is aborted/exception is raised,
> and log accordingly.